# Отличие динамических и статических переменных в с++

Tags: c++, c, переменные

Изучаю с++. Встретились такие переменные со звездочкой `*a`, а еще `void *arg`. Прочитал в инете, что это динамические переменные, но в чем суть так и не понял. Есть еще такие методы `void *thread_receive(void *arg)`. Помогите разобраться)

Comment: Читайте про указатели. *"динамические переменные"* Нет такого термина.

Comment: Это вопрос не для SO. Найдите учебник по C и прочитайте его от корки до корки. Там вы найдёте объяснение что такое "звёздочка" и зачем она нужна. Если у вас потом возникнут вопросы, задайте их тут. Пользы будет больше.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, какой учебник можете посоветовать?

Comment: [Jens Gustedt, Modern C](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-02383654/document).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это указатели, они не всегда указывают на динамически выделенную память, например

```
int a = 5;
int *aPtr = &a;
```

Тут aPtr указывает на статическую память.

```
int *ptr = new int;
```

А тут ptr указывает на динамически выделенную переменную

void* это указатель на что угодно

```
void *voidPtr = &a;
int *a1Ptr = voidPtr; //<- Но так писать нельзя (error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*')
int *a2Ptr = static_cast<int*>(voidPtr); //<- Так тоже
int *a3Ptr = (int*)voidPtr; //<- А так уже можно
```

Так же можно использовать указатель на указатель

```
int a = 5;
int *first = &a;
int **second = &first;
int ***third = &second;
```

И для обращение к искомой переменной соответственно

```
*first = 6; // a = 6
**second = 7; // a = 7
***third = 8; // a = 8
```

Это база, подробнее Вы можете прочитать на

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-c-examples/

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/pointers-cpp?view=msvc-160

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers.htm

Comment: `void *voidPtr = &a; int *a2Ptr = static_cast<int*>(voidPtr); //<- Так тоже` Так писать можно.